# Can I create separate ts file to write business logic for all the components in Angular 4 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created different components for each section of my UI and looking for a way to keep my business logic separate from the component.ts file. I am wondering if I can have below structure where component.ts will communicate with component.bl.ts and this bl.ts will communicate with component.service.ts

```
app  
 - configuration  
   - configuration-section.component.ts  
   - configuration-section.component.html  
   - configuration-section.component.css  
   - configuration-section.component.spec.ts  
   - configuration-section.component.bl.ts  
   - configuration-section.component.service.ts  
 - login  
   - login.component.ts  
   - login.component.html  
   - login.component.css  
   - login.component.spec.ts  
   - login.component.bl.ts  
   - login.component.service.ts
```

Comment: I think your looking for [services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#services)

Comment: Service holds reusable code. But If I write a business logic of component in service then it will not act as service. I'm confused where I should write a code that will hold the business logic of component which is not going to be reused in other components.

Comment: @VaibhavGhorpade Best option is to keep such BL in methods inside Service class and keep this service as a single instance (one which is not providedIn:root) This way your .ts will have single instance of service class, which will have BL, if you want to further seprate API calls then create a similar class which only have API methods, Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to mark your Business-Logic classes as `@Injectable()` as well and register them as provider within the modules that need these bl-classes.

Within the bl-classes you can then inject the other services and wrap that logic.

**Not directly related:** Using the word business-logic here makes me a little nervous. A front-end should not contain business-logic at all. Only application-logic. If you are looking for a modern and highly architectural way of developing your angular app, [NGRX](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) is the way to go.